# How to use Environment Module packages in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, environment-variables, mpi

I have been a while in Fedora and other Linuxes, and I got used to loading "environment modules".

For example, in Fedora, I could install both `mpich` and `openmpi` (two implementations of the same library, MPI), and I can switch between the two by doing `load module mpich` or `load module openmpi`.

In Ubuntu, instead, the two libraries coexist, for example, with different executables, `mpirun.mpich` or `mpirun.openmpi`.
Both approaches have their pros and cons, but **can I configure Ubuntu to do modules instead?**

Moreover, I just installed NVHPC (Nvidia compiler, etc.), and after manual installation (from a tar file), I saw the message:

```
...
generating environment modules for NV HPC SDK 23.7 ... done.
Installation complete.
HPC SDK successfully installed into /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk

If you use the Environment Modules package, that is, the module load
command, the NVIDIA HPC SDK includes a script to set up the
appropriate module files.

% module load /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/modulefiles/nvhpc/23.7
% module load nvhpc/23.7

Alternatively, the shell environment may be initialized to use the HPC SDK. ...
```

In this case, it would be very handy to be able to use modules instead of setting a lot of environment variables or polluting `.bashrc`.

**How can I configure Ubuntu to use these modules that were apparently just generated by the installation script?**

Of course, the command `module` doesn't work at the moment.

```
$ module load nvhpc/23.7
module: command not found
```

Comment: Have you actually installed the `environment-modules` package? It's in the `universe` repository - see [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if you're unsure.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at "Lmod" which re-implements and extends the functionality of environment modules. In that case, adding `family("mpi")` to the different modules means that only one can be loaded.

Comment: @steeldriver, I didn't (didn't know). But after installing it (`$ sudo apt install environment-modules`) I get an error with `$ module load nvhpc/23.7` -> `module: command not found`

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, how do I use `Lmod` in Ubuntu?

Comment: @alfC Install it then read the manual: https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/010_user.html

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, it seems I have to source `. /etc/profile` to start using the `module` command.